# Why passing pointer to array to a function needing pointer to int, works without error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Out of curiosity, I change the line to `set_array(&array1[0])` in the following from `set_array[array1]`, the parameter is not the same type, but it works, any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void set_array(int array[][9]);
int main(void) {
    int array1[4][9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            array1[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    set_array(&array1[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(array1 + i) + j));
            //printf("%d ", array1[i][j]);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
void set_array(int array[][9]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here array1 is having the address of whole array of 1st row(or column)depending upon implementation. `(&array1[0])`is same as `(array1)` of type `()[n]` sice array name itself contains the address of the ist element .But when you pass `(&array)` which of type `()[m][n]` and compiler will throw an error because mismatch of argument type.

I think you haven't read my comments in the last question you asked

Comment: Thanks man, and sorry about missing your comments in my last question

Answer (score 6):

In C the plain name of an array is the same as a pointer to its first element. This is called decaying of the array. See the [C faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) for further explanation.

Comment: *In this context*, the name of the array evaluates to a pointer to its first element. In other contexts in C, the two are not the same.